# JavaFx 2.x: BarChart with both axes as numbers

Tags: javafx-2, bar-chart, linechart

1) I want a BarChart where both axes are numbers(`<Number, Number>`), but it seems like this isn't supported and that you need to have a category and a number axis.

Is there a way to override the BarChart class to get both axes as Number, Number?

2) Is it possibile to use LineChart to plot bars instead of BarChart class to get a histogram plot ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a good solution: I suggest to do in this way

```
series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i, 0));
series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i, listValue));          
series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i, 0));
```

in this way you can use LineChart to plot bars

also, if you want to remove symbols from AreaChart you can accomplish this by using css

```
.chart-area-symbol 
            { -fx-background-color: null, null; }
```

Comment: Just a note - Instead of modifying the CSS, you can use chart.setCreateSymbols(false), you also don't need duplicated (i, 0) points

Answer (score 3):

You can try this solution

```
XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();                        
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i, i));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i, listValue));            
        lineChart.getData().addAll(series);
```

but I warn you it is very slow compared to Number axis